# Problem with TCP/IP port

Tags: 12.04

I have a vps with Ubuntu 12.04, I installed cccam, when I want to open the web like-it "31.X.X.X:XXXX" it will not open after that I knew the vps uses a nat ip address 10.X.X.X, I installed noip but still same problem, I typed in command putty (in vps) :

```
# sudo netstat -tlnpu
```

the result is:

```
                    Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State     
12240/CCcam.x86     tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:12000           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      
12240/CCcam.x86     tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:16001           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      
12240/CCcam.x86     tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:16000           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
```

means-it that the ports opened? where is the problem? What I have to do?
i need your help

Comment: English only, please translate. Anglais seulement, s'il vous plaît traduire

Answer (score 1):

So I'am assuming the output of:

```
:~# netstat -tlnpu
```

is not from the local system (your working computer), but from the machine that you have remotely connected to that is running the vps?. Than yes the process identification 12240 is currently using the local address (of the vps machine) on ports 12000, 16001, and 16000; and the ports are up and running.

In the configuration file of the camera software what are the specified ports? If the configuration file does not list ports 12000, 16001, 16000 than thats the problem and you edit it. Also where is the camera physically located?

Comment: it is not camera, CCcam server is a kind of cardsharing protocol, where “sharing” simply means the right to access digital packages by connecting to a CCcam cardsharing server .

Comment: the applictaion works well and I want to manage-it from my pc local  like-it "vpsip or hostname:port"